# Why is my message from the discord bot not being sent?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Below is my code, I wanted to know why the "==" operator isn't functioning as when I change it to "!=" the bot responds accordingly. I have typed "hello" in my discord server with the bot online however it doesn't respond.

```
import discord


client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content == "hello":
         await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the `message_content` intent, so you can't read messages. Hence, `message.content` will always be empty.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Comment: You can  do ```discord.Intents.all()``` to enable all intents if you are trying to enable a bunch of intents, makes it easier.

Comment: @ConnerWolf08 You should only enable intents that you actually plan on using, not randomly use `all()`. The entire reason the library forces you to explicitly pass intents now is to get people to read the docs and think about the intents they're requesting.